# Unable to convert _NSCFNumber to int

Tags: ios, objective-c, casting, long-integer, type-conversion

I have got the following code:

```
id value = characteristic.value;
long valueBefore = (long)characteristic.value;
int valueAfter = (int) valueBefore;
```

Which produces the following values:

[image]

When I look at **id value** I see "(long)6" which is the value I would expect (**6**). However, when I cast it to long I get **-5764..etc..781**. Why is that?

**How can I convert value to an int with value 6?** The debugger says that value is a **_NSCFNumber**.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is returning `NSNumber` so you have to get int value using bellow method instead of cast.

```
NSNumber *value = characteristic.value;
long valueBefore = [value longValue]
int valueAfter =  [value intValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try by casting like this:

```
Datatype variable = [value integerValue];
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: "typecasting" is something that happens to movie actors who always play similar roles. "casting" is an explicit request to the compiler to convert a value from one type to another. What you are doing is neither, it is calling a method of NSNumber. Which is the right thing to do, but it's not casting. And the left hand side should have type NSInteger.

Comment: @gnasher729 Thats my mistake, that I wrote Typecasting instead of casting, & in my answer I have just given a syntax where on left side we can add the appropriate data type & on right hand side we have to place code of it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`longValue` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSNumber/longValue) to get the wrapped value from the `NSNumber` object; you cannot cast the object to a primitive type:

```
NSNumber *numobj = characteristic.value;
long value = [numobj longValue];
```